# Delay the opacity of button on viewport position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button on the very bottom of my website which I want to be invisible until the page is scrolled to the bottom. Once scrolled to the bottom, the button animates in (opacity/visible animate to 1)

I have skrollr installed in the site already for other elements but not sure if I can accomplish this effect with scroller.

Basically, its an transition/animation on the button with a delay. Only activated once the site has reached the bottom.

HTML

```
<footer>

    <div class="footer-btn"><a href="...">Miss something?</a></div>

       ...
```

CSS

```
.footer-btn a  {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Change CSS to:

```
.footer-btn a  {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 25px 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

Put this on page as javascript:

```
var isShown = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        isShown = true;
        $('.footer-btn').fadeIn(500);
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() && isShown) {
        isShown = false;
        $('.footer-btn').fadeOut(500);
    }
})
```

Comment: I am using wordpress, can that go in the <head> tag. Also, will that animate or just show up

Comment: Yes, it can go anywhere really - you just need to wait for DOM to be ready. That will just display the button... if you want animation, you'd have to be more specific what.  Probably take a look at http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ for simple stuff.

Comment: i put it in <head> with <script> tags around it. in my css what do I need to set it as so it is invible to begin with? (visible: none, opacity: 0, etc?)

Comment: that's starting to work great, how can it fade back to 0 when the window is scrolled back up. Right now it fades in perfect once the bottom is reached, but it stays there once loaded. (sorry if i should have included this in my posted question)

Comment: Updated again - for future questions, however, you really should be more focused.  Asking for full solutions on SO like this is heavily frowned on.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't think of this part when I asked. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need javascript/jQuery. You can try using [waypoint.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) 
which makes triggering javascript events at certain points in the page easy!

```
var $footerbutton = $('.footer-btn a');
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
element: document.getElementById('#waypoint'),
handler: function() {
$footerbutton.css('opcaity',1);
}
 })
```

Comment: I am using Wordpress. Can i put that in my <head> in simple <script> tags?

Comment: I want it to happen I assume on load

Comment: Im not an expert on wordpress but I believe you can include a script tag in your header to include waypoint. Then waypoint triggers at certain points in the page, so adding onload is no necessary